# Upgrade Prestashop from 1.6.0.11 to 1.7 (latest version)

Tags: prestashop, upgrade, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I want to upgrade prestashop from 1.6.0.11 to 1.7 (latest version). First, I have tried 1-click upgrade but did not worked for me. See these screenshots http://prntscr.com/ek46kr, http://prntscr.com/ek46nb, http://prntscr.com/ek46sa. Second, I have tried with manual steps like this link http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Manual+update, but this also not worked ! See screenshot http://prntscr.com/ek4dbv

If anybody know perfect steps to upgrade prestashop 1.7 please answer here. It will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule or guidance to upgrade from 1.6 to 1.7.

From Prestashop developer blog: [Is it be easy to upgrade from previous versions of PrestaShop to v1.7?](http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-faq/#is-it-be-easy-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-prestashop-to-v17)

> In short: no, it won’t. You can upgrade, but be prepared to have to adapt or replace many of your addons (theme, modules).
>
> Now for the longer answer. PrestaShop 1.7 is a major version not only because it packs a lot of sweet changes, but it is also major in the SemVer sense of the term: it breaks some of the backward compatibility. If it didn’t, we probably would have called it 1.6.2.0 :)
>
> For starters, 1.6 themes will not work on 1.7. That’s a definite. We rewrote the way themes are made, and theme designers will be delighted to find in the new Starter Theme a solid foundation for their own themes. With this foundation, new themes can be created in half the time it took to create a 1.6 theme.
>
> Now, about modules. All well-written 1.6 modules should work with little to no changes in 1.7, except:
>
> - Those which target the theme/front office – because we rewrote the way themes are written.
> - Those which target the Product page – because the DOM of this page has changed.
> - Those which target the Modules page – again, because the DOM of this page has changed.
>
> What this means for any upgrade is that in order for a PS 1.6 to migrate to PS 1.7, you (or your agency) will have to:
>
> - Rewrite the theme, ideally using the Starter Theme or the default theme.
> - Adapt the Product page modules (CSS and JavaScript).
> - Adapt the Modules page modules (CSS and JavaScript).
> - Test all the other modules – as you would for any new release.
>
> In any case, we advise you to make sure that your module does work in
>   PrestaShop 1.7 before you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I want to offer one more solution, it’s simpler:

We have developed a data migration module PrestaShop 1.6–1.7, you can migrate your products, customers, orders, couriers, categories, manufacturers and much more.
And have already transferred several stores to the version of PrestaShop 1.7
The module can also transfer content from version 1.5 to 1.7
Currently available on PrestaShop Addons:
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/data-migration-backup/29736-1-click-prestashop-upgrade-16-to-17.html

We also assist in data transfer if you have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily migrate / upgrade your Prestashop from version 1.6 (or any older versions) to 1.7 using this free module: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/820013-migrate-or-upgrade-prestashop-16-or-other-versions-to-17-%E2%80%93-free-module/

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.