# Upgrading Prestashop from 1.7.0.3 to latest with 1-click Upgrade module

Tags: module, prestashop, upgrade, prestashop-1.7

I currently have a 1.7.0.3 Prestashop that I'd like to upgrade to the latest stable version. When I start upgrading from the 1-click Upgrade module, the latest version is downloaded correctly but I get an error about the backup name not specified. I then disabled this option of backing up files and database as I couldn't find where to fill in this information (I made manual backups).

I am then told that 17152 files have to be modified, whereas the version comparison tells me that only 5157 files need to be modified and 895 deleted. And the upgrade is stuck at 17152 files left with a great number of ajax calls being made until I get the following error:

> [Ajax / Server Error for action upgradeFiles] textStatus: "error " errorThrown:" " jqXHR: " "

As I was looking for a solution, I tried to upgrade from the local directory by choosing this option in the expert mode of the module. But when I save my choice, it is not taken into account and stays on the option "Major version", and therefore downloads the upgrade from Prestashop instead of using the local directory. I get the same result if I choose the option "Minor version". Debug mode brought nothing in the process.

How can I get the upgrade to work?

Comment: Hi again, which version of the 1 click upgrade module are you currently using?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The version is 2.1.0. I already tried to uninstall and install it again without any more success.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the 1 click upgrade module? You can find it here: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/data-migration-backup/5496-.html . I looked it up in one of my shops and the latest version is v 3.0.3 (in the backend of the shop, it has a different version number on addons). I'd like to suggest to download it and give it a try. Always backup your files and database first. Also, check your ftp (in the modules folder) if the files have been removed after uninstalling.

Comment: I actually downloaded the module from the shop itself. I tried downloading from the addon market, it is indeed the v3.0.3, but I get an error saying that the module is not compatible with my shop. It seems that I am stuck with v2.1.0. I opened a ticket on the Prestashop Forge about official modules, I hope they will reply.

Comment: Not all is lost ;) This version: http://build.prestashop.com/news/updated-1-click-upgrade-module/ saved my day once or twice as well. You can download it directly from that page and i really hope it will save your day as well...

Comment: I uploaded this version on my shop. The design is broken but I can start the update. Yet I have immediatly an alert saying I have a JSON error, and the console shows me the response "wrong token". I'm beginning to consider exporting my catalogue, install a new Prestashop, uploading my theme and importing back the catalogue...

Comment: With all you have been through and tried, I think your suggestion is the best option. Make sure you purchase a export module with good reviews, because there are a lot of bad ones on the market (even on addons). You could also take a look at https://mypresta.eu. These modules are written by a renounded developer and trustworthy. You could also look for a module named migration pro, that one might also suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into these. Will the export and import work from an older PS version to the latest?

Comment: Yes it will. When you use an export module (which exports a CSV file for example), you use the prestashop import option which you will find at the advanced settings. I don't know if your products have attributes, but make sure you find a export module which also exports the combinations properly. When you use the import function, you'll be able to link the CSV fields (you'll see, it's pretty easy).

Answer (score -1):

You can NOT do that with the 1-click module.
Read more here: http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-faq/#is-it-be-easy-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-prestashop-to-v17

It's also discussing on this topic: [Upgrade Prestashop from 1.6.0.11 to 1.7 (latest version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801959/upgrade-prestashop-from-1-6-0-11-to-1-7-latest-version)

However you can migrate your data from your old Prestashop website to Prestashop 1.7 using this free module: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/820013-migrate-or-upgrade-prestashop-16-or-other-versions-to-17-%E2%80%93-free-module/

Answer (score -4):

You can not update PrestaShop 1-Click Upgrade with PrestaShop 1 to upgrade PrestaShop from version 1.6 to 1.7. So these versions have completely different structure and are incompatible between itself.

But you can import data from version 1.6 or another version to version 1.7 [using our module](https://addons.prestashop.com/ru/data-migration-backup/29736-1-click-upgrade-or-migrate-to-17-pro.html).

This is a paid module, 199 euros, but it can help with such problems when other options do not work.