# Can't edit product when two categories have the same name

Tags: prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on a Prestashop 1.7.0.3 and I encountered a problem.
The shop is selling car parts, so I have categories for all the makes and then subcategories for all the models. As it happens, some models have the same name but they are built by different carmakers (for exemple, BMW 323 and MAZDA 323).
So I have two categories that have the same name (323) but belonging to two different parent categories (BMW and MAZDA).

The problem is, when I try to edit the products that belong to those subcategories in the back office, I get an error saying "Unable to update settings". In the Chrome console, I can see that the POST request gets a 400 error (Bad Request) and the preview response is "step1_categories_tree: [This value is not valid]".

Editing products that belong in subcategories with unique names works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the category url's. If they are the same, the duplicate url's are the cause so change those. I also recommend to update to the latest version of prestashop 1.7 (1.7.2.2), check your modules and theme first if they are compatible with the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, but URL's are different (there is the category id in them) so it's not that. As to the update, I also have a problem doing that. I asked about it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091487/upgrading-prestashop-from-1-7-0-3-to-latest-with-1-click-upgrade-module)

Comment: I did some searching for you online (and i also tried to recreate the error, but...) this is a Prestashop bug, which has been fixed since version 1.7.0.6. So the problem which needs to be fixed is getting it to update like you commented.